# How to calculate average users visits per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a requests table which include request data for my my page requests. I have field including Id, UserAgent, Ip, EventDateUtc, etc. How to write SQL which give me average requests per day.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a `count` grouped by `UserAgent,EventDateUtc` and then do a `AVG` on top of it.

```
SELECT AVG(reccount) avg_count,EventDateUtc
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) reccount,UserAgent, CONVERT(DATE,EventDateUtc) EventDateUtc
FROM PageVisit
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,EventDateUtc),UserAgent
)T
GROUP BY EventDateUtc
```

If you want a total average for all days, don't do a GROUP BY in the outer query.

```
SELECT AVG(reccount) avg_count
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) reccount,UserAgent, CONVERT(DATE,EventDateUtc) EventDateUtc
FROM PageVisit
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,EventDateUtc),UserAgent
)T
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner select counts visits / day, the outer the average:

```
select avg(cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from tablename
      group by EventDateUtc)
```

Comment: I just need Date part

Comment: Can you add sample table data, and expected result, to the question?